# jsTree select Node which is not in DOM yet

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have an jsTree, data comes from HTML

```
$("#tree_container").jstree();
```

Now I want to implement deep linking on the tree elements. I am getting the class and data-id from URL parameters and now I want to select the correspondent node.

```
var id=$("#tree_container").find("li."+get_class+"[data-id='"+get_id+"']").attr("id");
if(id!=undefined && id!=0) {
                treeElem.jstree(true).select_node(id);
            }
```

This only works if the node is already in the DOM Tree.
(sub-Trees are getting inserted in if the parent node is clicked)
If the node I want is not in the tree ... id is undefined and the select fails.

Thing is, if I put in the id (like "#j1_6") in directly the node is found even if it is not in the DOM tree. It only work with the Id in that format, I try putting other selectors in or even elements ($(".class[data-id='1']"), nothing worked.

My problem is that I do not know how to get the id of the node if it is not in the DOM Tree yet. I did not find a api function or anything to do that.

====== UPDATE ======

I found a workaround ... 
When building the HTML tree I now combine the class and data-id to make up the html id of the element (li).
So I have controll over the ids and know them and just do:

`treeElem.jstree(true).select_node("#"+get_type+"_"+get_id);`

so yeah, as I said for me it is just a workaround...

Comment: Can you show the code where you insert branch into a clicked parent node?

Comment: i am not clicking anything. I take the parameters (get_class,get_id) form the URL and then I want to select the corresponding node in the tree.

Comment: If you have `data-id` attribute for li why don't you just change it to `id` and use it to get node instead of constructing an id from class and data-id?

Comment: it is what I finally did (see update), but I have elements of two types (classes).